# What do bats do if played ultra sound?

Tags: ethology, echolocation, bats

If there are bats flying in the cave, and I play the same pitch they use to echolocate from a speaker, what would the bats do?

Comment: they shouldn't be able to orientate...

Answer (score 1):

Depends completely on how good ultrasound you are producing.

**Will they interpret your signal as an obstacle ?**

Not really until you produce signals exactly calculated for the distance and speed of bat from obstacle. Here something known as dopler effect will come into play which will make bats understand probably thats not their sound. Otherwise every bat would have made a noise to divert another bat.

**Is just making sound good for dislocating**

Well, till this date we don't know what humans are speaking from their sound waves what you can guess for bat for what they did just speak. If you listen closely to bat sound you will find amplitude variation at non-constant duration.

[Here is a detail of what else bats use](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/sonar-echolocation-bats/) . Its harmonics that takes sleep of physicists.

Comment: I don't understand the second section

Comment: its hard to explain in much detail the second point but just understand that bat get reflected voice from multiple incident points. Replicating such voice using single source generator won't be any effective. More simply, have you  ever been tricked by mobile sound as real human voice at some distance?